# Jmeter concurrent user load Test Plan

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I am new to Jmeter. My project Manager said to me to test the website load with 100 concurrent user.

Following functionality of website considering to load test-

1. User Registration

   - Get Registration Page Request
   - Post Registration Page Request
2. Login and User profile navigation

   - Get Login Page request
   - Post Login page request
   - Get User Dashboard request
   - Get edit Profile page request
   - Get change password request
   - Get Invite Friend Page request

My Test Scenario is 50 concurrent user Accessing **Registration** page and other 50 concurrent user accessing **User profile**(login,dashboard, etc) .
I have created following test plan for the same -

[image]

And did thread configurations for registration and Login same as -

Total No of Threads : 50

Rampup period : 600 sec

Duration of holding load : 3600 sec

Configured constant timer (delay for each request 200 ms) for both Thread Group requests also added some listeners for collecting the result. I have following question -

1. Is it correct way to include these many request in test plan for complete load test of My website ?
2. Do I have configured right thread properties or what else I can do for achieve the best ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Think Time

   Your test plan looks good, however the current configuration doesn't represent 100 concurrent users as 200ms think time is something for "superhuman". Real users "think" for a longer period between operations and it should vary depending on the nature of simulated request. So I would suggest using individual [Uniform Random Timers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Uniform_Random_Timer) with the relevant think time ranges for each request.
2. Overall Test Design from the "reality" perspective

   If you have some extra time you could think about bringing more reality into your simulation like:

   - X users perform registration
   - Y users editing their profiles
   - Z users inviting friends
   - etc.

   So distribution would represent normal anticipated usage of your application. Your load test should be as realistic as possible, only this way you will be able to tell for sure "my application is able to support this many users providing reasonable response time". Take a look at [Throughput Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller)
3. Overall Performance

   - Disable `Active Threads Over Time` and especially `View Results in Table` listeners during test run
   - Configure PerfMon Metrics Collector listener to store the captured values into a file. Later you will be able to open the file and analyze the metrics
   - [Run the test in non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
   - follow other recommendations from [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure)

Comment: @Dimitri T, Thanks you so much for answer. By mistake i have wrote constant timer as 200ms although it was 2000ms. I have 'added Uniform random time' with configuration 'Random Delay Maximum = 2000ms' and 'Constant Delay Offset =5000' for each request. So far i know, it adds delay for each request between 2000-7000ms . Is it fine settings for the thread group as I configured above ?

Comment: Your new configuration means delay between 5000 - 7000 ms before each request, if you are looking for 2000-7000 then you need to set Constant Delay to 2000 and Random Delay to 5000, check out [A Comprehensive Guide to Using JMeter Timers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/comprehensive-guide-using-jmeter-timers) for detailed explanation.